# Ransack Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I just added Ransack to my small ticket system site.

My tickets_controller

```
    def index
    @q = Ticket.search(params[:q])
    @tickets = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @tickets = Ticket.all
    end
```

My Tickets Index View

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
<%= f.label :body_cont, "Ticket Title" %>
<%= f.text_field :body_cont %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I want to search if the body of my ticket contains the search value.

And after the search form I have a Table that is displaying all my tickets

Here is a part of that table

```
        <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
    <tr>
            <td><%= ticket.id %></td>
            <td><%= link_to ticket.title, ticket_path(ticket) %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.body %></td>
            <td><%= ticket.created_at %></td>
            <td><%= time_ago_in_words(ticket.updated_at) %></td>
```

When I start a search (for example with the word "server") nothing happens. I don't get any error... Nothing happens...

Do you have any idea whats wrong?

Update: No Idea?

**Update 2:**

When I start a search (searched for server) i get the following output in my console:

```
    Started GET "/tickets?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Btitle_cont%5D=server" for 127.0.0.1 at         2014-03-25 10:41:45 +0100
  Processing by TicketsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"title_cont"=>"server"}}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY      "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tickets"
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tags"
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments"
  Ticket Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tickets"
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."ticket_id" = ?      [["ticket_id", 5]]
  Tag Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" =     "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."ticket_id" = ?  [["ticket_id", 5]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."ticket_id" = ?  [["ticket_id",     6]]
   Tag Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" =   "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."ticket_id" = ?  [["ticket_id", 6]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."ticket_id" = ?  [["ticket_id", 7]]
  Tag Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" =  "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."ticket_id" = ?  [["ticket_id", 7]]
  Rendered tickets/index.html.erb within layouts/application (16.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 27.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

**Update 3:**

My Ticket Controller looks like this for def index

```
    def index
    @q = Ticket.search(params[:q])
    @ticket = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @ticket = Ticket.paginate(:page => params[:page],  :per_page => 3)
end
```

But still not working

Update 4:

Hey guys,

I found the error! It was the combination of Ransack and Will_Paginate. I found the solution here: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/80

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does the server log says when you perform a search? You see the DB queries there and should be able to see what goes wrong.

Comment: I think you need to comment out or remove the line `@tickets = Ticket.all`